# Вопрос по отладке ошибок

Tags: java, android, обработка-ошибок

Есть ли способ отлавливания ошибок в Android-приложении, когда телефон не находится в отладке и во время тестирования приложения произошла ошибка. Чтобы потом не воспроизводить её заново, а просто посмотреть в чем причина?

Comment: ведите логи работы приложения и пишите их в файл

Comment: Это да, а нет другого способа?

Comment: ну а что вы хотите то? Можете обернуть весь код в try catch и выдавать AlertDialog с ошибкой если уж так всё плохо

Comment: 2 непонянтых пункта. Что значит не находится в отладке не запущен ADB ?
Во время какого тестирования? Дебажная версия установлена или релизная.

Comment: 1 пункт: Не находится в отладке, значит не подсоединен USB-кабель к телефону.
2 пункт: дебажная версия

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая вопрос и комментарии, очень советую Crashlytics (Fabric.io). Всё чаще встречается в проектах, легко устанавливается,

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

имеет kits для NDK, что очень важно, отличный анализ, быстрый бек, на FireBaseService крутиться, фильтр StackTrace красив, схож на PlayConsole, и это удобно.

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install